# How to make Composer/PSR-4 make accepting my second namespace in a subfolder?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, psr-4

Given is a Symfony 4.4 Application (specifically, Sylius) using **PSR-4** for autoloading:

```json
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "KYCBundle\\": "src/KYCBundle/"
        }
    },
```

Placing all Controllers and Entities and so on under the `src` directory works well so far:

```
+ src
  - Controllers
  - Entities
```

And the corresponding namespace is e.g.:

```php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;
```

But for the second namespace `KYCBundle` this does not work.

```
+ src
   + KYCBundle
     - Controllers
     - Command
     - Entities
```

When I want to use Classes with the following namespace declaration:

```
namespace KYCBundle\Command\AccessTokenCommand
```

this will give an error:

> Expected to find class "App\KYCBundle\Command\AccessTokenCommand" in
> file "     ./src/KYCBundle/Command/AccessTokenCommand.php" while
> importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not
> found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.

When I change the namespace from `KYCBundle\Command` into `App\KYCBundle\Command` thinks work well. Also, when I delete the second Line in PSR-4 configuration, things will not change which basically means that whether with or without the PSR-4 configuration for `KYCBundle` is not used at all.

How to let me use the namespace `KYCBundle` as the root level without the prefix `App`?

Comment: The real culprit here is autowire.  By default it scans the src directory and gets confused by the multiple namespaces.  Exclude the src/KYCBundle directory or turn off autowire and this particular error will go away.  But it's best to do as suggested below and only have one namespace per directory.  Personally I would make a src-kyc directory but the actual name is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do  not put the classes from your second namespace within `src`. Avoid having nested namespaces "roots".

Either put your second namespace outside `src`. E.g.:

```
- ./src
- ./KYCBundle
```

Or have different roots within `src`:

```
- ./src/App
- ./src/KYCBundle
```

Logically, modify your `composer.json` file to match your directory structure.